# Insert Public Key into a KeyStore programatically

Tags: java, ssl, key-pair

I want to generate a key pair and insert the public and private keys into different keystores, to be used as KeyStore and TrustStore in an SSL Socket connection. I generate the KeyPair using a KeyPairGenerator, and I already have generated a signing certificate for the chain using java's keytool. Then I can insert the private key into a KeyStore like this:

```
PublicKey publicKey;
PrivateKey privateKey;

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keyStore.load(null, "storepass".toCharArray());

keyStore.setKeyEntry("privatekey", privateKey, "keypass".toCharArray(), chain);
```

Using this keystore I can create a KeyManager for the SSL connection. But to create a TrustManager, I need the public key stored into a KeyStore as well, so I tried storing the public key in a key store:

```
PublicKey publicKey;

KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keyStore.load(null, "storepass".toCharArray());

trustStore.setKeyEntry("publickey", publicKey, "public".toCharArray(), chain);
```

This returns an error: `java.security.KeyStoreException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys`
So I tried using `setCertificateEntry()`, but this doesn't work since it's a `PublicKey` object and I need a `Certificate`. So my question is, how can I store the PublicKey in a KeyStore programatically? Using keytool is not an option.

Comment: You can't; as you found, `KeyStore` doesn't support bare publickey. Even if `keytool` were an option it can't do that either. 
And even if you could, you couldn't use it for SSL/TLS in Java because the standard protocol requires an X.509 certificate (chain); there is theoretically an option to do otherwise (rfc7250) but JSSE doesn't implement it, and I don't know any other implementation that does.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Actually, it's working using this article: http://bfo.com/blog/2011/03/08/odds_and_ends_creating_a_new_x_509_certificate/ , and I've succesfully encrypted data with the private key and decrypted it with the certificate generated by this method. I can also succesfully create an TLSv1.2 connection, as long as I use SSLSocket.setUseClientMode(false), otherwise I get an error `javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 1`. As soon as I fix that, I'll post my own answer.

Comment: That article has you create a `Certificate` and not just a bare public key. You may have solved the problem you were trying to solve, but the answer to your actual question is that "Java's KeyStore class won't allow you to work directly with public key entries".

Comment: For future travelers - I've pulled the code @ConnerDassen links (thanks) into a more end-to-end example: https://github.com/Erhannis/TlsChannelTest .  It programmatically generates keys, attempts a TLS connection (over TCP by default), asks if you want to trust unrecognized certificates, and adds them to a truststore so it won't ask again next time.